# Force apt-get to install later version of nodejs

Tags: debian, apt, node.js

I am on Debian 11, fully up to date (`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade`). I previously installed `nodejs` version 12.22, since that is what is in the Debian repo, like so:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
$ node -v
v12.22.5
```

However I want to use v14.18. I removed all traces of node version 12, like so:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge nodejs
```

And then added the PPA for nodejs using https://github.com/nodesource/distributions:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x -o nodesource_setup_14_lts.sh
$ sudo bash nodesource_setup_14_lts.sh
```

I can see that it has added the new PPA under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list 
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x bullseye main
deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x bullseye main
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:2 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
Hit:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x bullseye InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

But now when I go to install `nodejs` it still uses version 12 :(

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs --dry-run
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst nodejs (12.22.5~dfsg-2~11u1 Debian:11.1/stable, Debian-Security:11/stable-security [i386])
Conf nodejs (12.22.5~dfsg-2~11u1 Debian:11.1/stable, Debian-Security:11/stable-security [i386])
```

It seems that `apt-get` is not using the new PPA to decide the version of `nodejs` to install. How can I install v14.18 systemwide?

**Edit**

Note that I am using a 32-bit machine:

```
$ uname -m
i686
```

When I do the above procedure on my other 64 bit machine it works fine and it installs version 14.18 from the PPA.

Extra requested information:

```
$ apt-cache policy nodejs
nodejs:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 12.22.5~dfsg-2~11u1
  Version table:
     12.22.5~dfsg-2~11u1 500
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian bullseye/main i386 Packages
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: when I look on the side, I can not find 32-bit packages. `apt-cache policy nodejs` please.

Comment: @nobody as you noted, i am using a 32 bit computer. i will update the question with additional information

Comment: I'm not an expert, maybe it is possible to crosscompile it on your 64-bit system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i386 builds has been dropped . [See Available architectures](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debian-and-ubuntu-based-distributions)

> NodeSource will continue to maintain the following architectures and may add additional ones in the future.

```
amd64 (64-bit)
armhf (ARM 32-bit hard-float, ARMv7 and up: arm-linux-gnueabihf)
arm64 (ARM 64-bit, ARMv8 and up: aarch64-linux-gnu)
```

You have to install `nodejs` from debian repositories instead of node repo.